# Efficient creation time descending lookup in Raik

Tags: sorting, nosql, riak

I'm learning to use Raik, the NoSQL engine. Given that I have a user "timeline" with posts, and that post may range from millions to billions, how can I take the last N posts from the raik bucket? I mean, the last created.

I read that when using a Secondary Index Raik will return posts ordered by key. So I decided to use an UUID1 for post keys and to have a Secondary Index for the post author, so that I can take all posts from that author using it's key.

However the posts are sorted ASCENDING! I also want to use the max_results parameter as the SQL LIMIT.

This query however returns the FIRST N posts of that user, not the last. Given that I already saw some StackOverflow posts, and that the proposed solution, MapReduce is not efficient for big buckets, how would you model data or write the query?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When coming from a SQL environment it is easy to treat a bucket as a table and store small individual records there, often relying on secondary indexes to get the data out. As Riak is a key-value store that uses consistent hashing, this is however often not the most efficient or scalable approach.

A lookup based on key in Riak allows the partitions holding the data to be directly identified, and the coordinating node can directly query these partitions. When querying a [secondary index](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/dev/advanced/2i/), Riak does not know on which partitions data that may match the index will reside. It will therefore need to send the query to a large number of partitions in order to ensure that all matching objects can be found. This is known as a 'coverage query' and means that, assuming n_val of 3 is used for the bucket, at least 1/3 of all partitions need to be queried. This generally leads to higher load on the cluster and does not scale as well as direct key lookups. Latencies also tend to be higher.

When using Riak it is therefore often recommended that you structure your data so that you can use direct key lookups as much as possible, e.g. through de-normalization.

If your messages/posts can be grouped some way, e.g. by user or conversation, it may make sense to store them in a single object representing this grouping instead of as separate objects.

If we assume that your posts can consist of either text or images and are linked to a conversation thread, you could create an object representing the conversation thread. This would contain information about the conversation as well as a list of posts. This list of posts can e.g. contain the id of the poster, a timestamp and the key of the record containing the post. If the post is a reasonably short text message it may even contain the entire post, reducing the number of records that will need to be fetched.

As posts come in to this conversation, the record is updated and the list of posts gets longer. It may be wise to set `allow_mult` to true in order to enable siblings, as this will allow you to handle concurrent writes. This approach allows you to always get the conversation as well as the latest posts through a single direct key lookup.

Riak works best when the size of objects are kept below a couple of MB. You will therefore need to move the oldest posts off to a separate object at some point to keep the size in check. If you keep a list of these related objects in the main conversation object, possibly together with some information about the time interval they cover, you can easily access these through direct key lookup as well if you should need to scroll back over older posts.

As the most common query usually is for the most recent entries, this can always be fulfilled through the main conversation object.

I would also like to point out that we do have a very active [mailing list](http://lists.basho.com/mailman/listinfo/riak-users_lists.basho.com) where these kind of issues are discussed quite frequently.

Comment: Thank you so much for the extensive reply. You just stopped me from using secondary indexes for any kind of has_many/one relation. In another thread on SO, it was suggested to use a linked list approach, using the 'Link' header to mimic the previous/next chain, and to have a 'first' link on the user, or conversation. This would require N lookups for N posts. When N is small (< 10), are timings acceptable for a web application? The only alternative is your grouping, but *allow_mult* scares me. I'd need to merge the two sibilings. Keeping the posts isolated would prevent double writes (99.999%).

Comment: Secondary indexes have many uses, including being used to indicate the parent object in one-to-many relations. The important thing is to design the model so that this is not the primary access method, especially if you have an application with a high read to write ratio. I would also recommend not trying to maintain a linked list using links or references in the object as this easily can break if you have concurrent updates/inserts and/or network partitions.

Comment: Enabling siblings does not have to be scary. In this case you could treat the list of posts as a set. If you encounter siblings you perform a set union between the available sets, then sort them by timestamp before writing it back to Riak. If you however have a very high posting frequency resulting in frequent updates, it can be difficult to resolve the siblings properly. In this case it is often recommended to try and funnel all the writes/updates through a single (or small number of) threads to reduce the risk of sibling explosion.

Comment: Ok. It is clear why linked lists are bad. The only issue with the grouping method, is that I will not have a single entity representing *the post*, and it can only be read when the conversation and a subset of posts is read too. I believe that it's here where denormalization takes place. I need a *conversation* (with groups of sorted posts) bucket and a *posts* bucket (with single posts). Thank you for your time :)

Comment: The ideal solution to your problem will depend on your access patterns. If you have a high write/read ratio, secondary indexes may be the right choice, but if your application is read heavy it often makes sense to roll your own indexes like I described, since it provides more efficient retrieval. A useful blog post explaining this can he found here: http://basho.com/index-for-fun-and-for-profit/

Answer (score 0):

I know it's probably too late to help you, but I found this post through wondering about the same thing.  The workaround I have come up with and been using to good effect is to create two secondary indexes, one with the real timestamp, and another that is (MAX_DATE - timestamp).  Performing lookups on the first query gets ascending results, and performing lookups on the second query gets descending results (once you do the math to turn it back into a real date).  You can find the max date value in the Javascript specification, such as reported in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), which is 8640000000000000.  I can't speak to how performant it is under really heavy load, but I can tell you that for my purposes it has been blazingly fast and I'm very satisfied.  I just came here hoping to find a less hacky way to do it.